# Tabela de usuários com mesmos usernames

Tags: mysql

Em uma tabela do banco MySQL, eu possuo cadastro de novos usuários, sendo que a chave primária da tabela é um campo de ID. Contudo, eu posso acabar criando, nem que seja por acidente, usuários com mesmo username.

Por exemplo, "joao.silva" pode ser cadastrado pra usuários chamados "João Carlos da Silva" e "João Silva Neto". Só que aí o login só vai funcionar pra um deles.

Existe alguma configuração que possa ser feita no MySQL pra que essa tabela não permita usernames idênticos?

Comment: Sim, torne essa coluna uma `unique key`

Comment: Bom, o correto seria você realizar um select na hora do cadastro, verificando se a um nome igual ao tentando cadastrar, se não houver cadastra normal, caso contrario exibe mensagem que usuário já existe!

Comment: @rray Sabe como eu posso fazer isso via Adminer ou através de alguma instrução SQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15255304/4190610

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Torna essa coluna uma unique key isso vai retornar um erro quando um valor já existente for inserido ou atualizado:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD UNIQUE INDEX `nome_indice` (`coluna`);
```

Answer (score 4):

O meio mais seguro seria adicionar uma constraint unica, desta forma de maneira alguma terá usernames iguais.

Na sua aplicação você trata o erro de código "1062" que é relativa a essa violação de chave única e retorna uma mensagem informando.

O código para adicionar essa chave depois da tabela criada é o seguinte:

```
ALTER TABLE tb_usuarios
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_usuario_unico UNIQUE (campo_user)
```

Onde tb_usuarios é a sua tabela, uc_usuario_unico é um identificador para essa chave única e campo_user é o campo que deverá ser único.